# How do I set a textfields string to a variable in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, xcode, macos

I want to set the text in a text field to a variable, in this case called variable1. Here's the part of my script.

```
on button836_(sender)
    set variable1 to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Choose")
```

That's the first part. But I also wanted to set the text in `textField` to the value of `variable1`.

I tried doing this:

```
    textField's setString:variable1
```

But it didn't work. Usually, I have a script that returns the value, and doing `textField86's setString:script837` etc. usually works, but it's different here. I even tried this stupid solution:

```
    set variable1script to do shell script "echo " & variable1
    textField's setString:variable1script
    end button836_
```

Which should work but it just tells me:

```
2015-11-26 15:12:27.077 [etc.] AppDelegate button836:]: -[NSTextField setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6100001e0200 (error -10000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a method from the **NSControl** class --> [Getting and Setting the Control’s Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html)

```
textField's setStringValue:variable1 -- variable1 must contains a string
```

Comment: Hm. When do you use `setStringValue` and when do you use `setString`. Do you use value when it is a direct value, and do you use `setString` when the value is returned of something?

Comment: **setString** is a method for these classes ( `NSTextView`, `NSMutableString` and `SFAuthorizationView`), not for the `NSTextField` class.

Comment: You can use a direct value or a returned value.